# How can I run Heroku server 24/7

Tags: heroku

I need to be able to run my Heroku app 24/7 even when no one is currently viewing it. It's primarily a server side application that I need to constantly be running at all times.

What's the cheapest and best way to go about doing this. I don't mind paying as long as I'm not paying unnecessarily.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options:

- Hobby subscription
- Free Web Dyno
- Free Worker Dyno

(1) Go for the **Hobby** subscription: 7$ per month, the Dyno is 24/7 up and running

(2) Use the **Free** tier, register a valid credit card which gives you extra free Dyno hours (total of 1000 hours) and make sure the Dyno is always up.
The Free **Web Dyno** sleeps after 30 min inactivity (ie no incoming requests for 30 minutes): you can prevent this sending a request (from an external tool or script) every 20 min.

(3) Use the **Free** tier (again register a valid credit card to be eligible to 1000 free hours)  with a **Worker Dyno** only (free worker dyno do not sleep)

More info at [Free Dyno Sleeping](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping)

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I decided to do option 1 and pay for the Dyno. However it still seems to shut off after midnight and I have to do "heroku restart" the following morning to turn it back on. Any idea as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Yes, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64859732/9095551

Comment: That's unfortunate. I'd be willing to upgrade to professional as I really need this to run 24/7, though is there a better alternative than heroku? I got at least 2 app I need constantly running and I'm fine with paying, but I dont want to pay unnecessarily when theres a better option.

Comment: I use DigitalOcean, cheap and you get what you need. Easy to work with Docker. See another of my aswers about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/63241267/9095551

Comment: thanks again! Does Digital Ocean have Postgres database support?

Comment: Yes https://www.digitalocean.com/products/managed-databases/ but it is not free. I use sometimes Atlas Mongo which has a free-tier