# Is there a way to prevent cycling from heroku?

Tags: heroku

I want to host my discord bot 24/7, but my bot cycled by heroku every day so it had some downtime. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Dynos restart every 24hrs, this is done for all Dynos and you cannot avoid it.

There is the option to [preboot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preboot) web Dynos (redirect traffic during the restart) but it comes only with the  more expensive subscriptions.